# Do Spring LDAP and Spring Cloud Consul work together?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, spring-ldap, spring-cloud-consul

I had a project with Spring LDAP in place.  I am trying to put in Spring Consul into this project and have been facing issues with respect to it.

Here is the pom.xml :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is application properties :

```
#consul properties
spring.cloud.consul.config.format=PROPERTIES
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.healthCheckPath=/<root>/health
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.healthCheckInterval=15s
spring.application.name=<App_Name>
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

And I enabled discovery client using @EnableDiscoveryClient on SpringBootApplication class.

But, I am ending up with this error and the app never starts :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field ldapTemplate in com.<package>.config.LdapClient required a bean of type 'org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'ldapTemplate' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:62703', transport: 'socket'
```

I figure it has something to do with autodiscovery of Ldap and introducing Consul is causing this issue, but, I am not able to pin-point the problem.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?